# If post content exists (any post content), do not display featured image

Tags: post-content

If post content exists, do not display featured image, if it does not exists, then display featured image or url. So, basically I want featured image to be displayed only if nothing else in post content to be displayed. Thanks!!!!

Comment: What have you tried thus-far? You'll need to show effort on your part, not just your need for an answer.

Comment: I have this so far, it looks for the shorcodes and then displays them if found in the homepage, if not then featured image is displayed. Basically, I want featured image or anything else to be displayed if no other content, but if there is a content then I dont want image or url to be displayed, just a post content.

Comment: Here is the code so far: <?php
        $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all("/$pattern/s", get_the_content(), $matches);
  
  
  echo preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/s", 'do_shortcode_tag', $matches[0][0] );
  
  ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the raw post content without any filters:

```
if ( "" === $post->post_content )
{
     the_post_thumbnail();
}
else
{
    the_content();
}
```

Comment: Do I do this in loop or function.php? Thanks

Comment: In a loop. You could encapsulate it in a function and move it to the `functions.php` but I think just using it as showed here will be easier to understand later.

Comment: Your code works same as what I had: <?php $pattern = get_shortcode_regex(); $matches = array(); preg_match_all("/$pattern/s", get_the_content(), $matches); echo preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/s", 'do_shortcode_tag', $matches[0][0] ); ?> . I just cant figure out how to display post content without featured image showing up? But, I do want the featured image to show up if nothing else in post. Thanks again....

Comment: I am not sure I can follow. Could you try to edit your question to make that easier to understand?

Comment: Sorry 4 that, your code works great, it displays whatever is in the post content. For example if I have a post with the post content in it and there is also a featured image there too, I want some kind of code to ignore the featured image and only to display the post content; on the other hand, if there is nothing in post to be displayed, then I want that featured image to be displayed. This is all done in the front page (homepage), so there is always going to be something to be displayed no matter if its post or featured image....Thanks

Comment: But why do you include the featured image in the post content if don’t want to show it always? The problem here is: _featured_ is an attribute for all sizes of this one image, so it might be part of the content in a different size. Hard to find.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The featured image is there so it can take over the post if no post content is available, its just like a "filler" for empty post content. So, if no post to be posted, the image shows up instead, and if there is a post content then, featured image do not show. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the code completely worked after I added it after: <?php else : ?> in my code in loop.php. Thanks again....

Answer (score 0):

Inside the template file with the loop you'd want something like encased in PHP tags...

```
( empty( get_the_content() ) ) ? the_post_thumbnail() : the_content();
```

Comment: `get_the_content()` can be filled by plugins with extra strings and might not be empty even if the `post_content` is empty.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't think of that...thank you for the insight :)